# Cocoa Interface Builder - Number Formatter Bug?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to put in a range using a Number Formatter component added to a text file. The problem occurs when I input a consistent sequence of number '9'. The field will keep on adding to what is in there ( i .e. 99999999999) up to a 10th number, and then the field will be changed to a random 6 digit number?

Is that a bug with the Number Formatter? Any workarounds?

Also, can I create my own number formatter? That would be the best if a bug does exist I think.

Thanks!

Comment: is it always the same 6 digit number? and if so: which?

Comment: No, it's totally random as far as I can see.. The strange thing is that only the number 9 seems to be 'breaking' the number formatter..

Also, in this case, the min and max range don't seem to work, as in, no action is taken by the Number Formatter if I enter a smaller or a large number than those that I specified in interface builder.. Strange.

Comment: Actually, it's not totally random..

30047
44703
65407
65407
65407
65407

The first two are different and then the number 65407 is always displayed after I enter 9999999999.. 

Thing is, I have no mention of 65407 in my code..

Comment: hm it is near my suspection... 
the datatype unsigned int16 can hold a maximum of 65535, you are not far from that value... and 99999999999 certainly is an overflow of this datatype. what type has your variable?

Comment: It is a int type, maybe you are right then about the overflow..

However, since  specify a maximum value in the number formatter in the Interface Builder, I shouldn't be allowed to enter 99999999999 in the first place...

Comment: please add some code for your numberformatter, and your method of input. maybe it'll be easier to see whats going on then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same thing on another version of Xcode and it seems to works fine.. Maybe a problem with that version's number formatter..

Thanks for your help.